# How to move new rows to top of sheet in Google Sheets using Google Apps Script and onEdit() function?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to move rows to a different sheet based on cell value. Right now, if "Complete" is checked off then the row will move to the "Complete" tab. However, the row will move to the bottom (If there are already filled out rows in the Completed tab), how could I code it so that each new row moves to the top of the spreadsheet? In my head it could get complicated because all the other rows would have to move one down to leave the top empty.

```
function onEdit(e) {
 const src = e.source.getActiveSheet();
 const r = e.range
 const row = r.getRow()
 const col = r.getColumn()

if(col!=11||row==1){return;}

if(e.value == "Complete")
 {
   const dest3 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Complete"); 
   src.getRange(row,1,1,11).moveTo(dest3.getRange(dest3.getLastRow()+1,1,1,11)); 
   src.deleteRow(row);
}
}
```

[This is the source sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6bYM.png)
[This is the destination sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQbvL.png)

Comment: Trying inserting a row just before the top and write to that row

Answer (score 0):

Simply have to insert a row before the first row and then move to that row.

```
dest3.insertRows(2);
```

```js
function onEdit(e) {
 const src = e.source.getActiveSheet();
 const r = e.range
 const row = r.getRow()
 const col = r.getColumn()

if(col!=11||row==1){return;}

if(e.value == "Complete")
 {
   const dest3 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Complete");
   dest3.insertRows(2);
   src.getRange(row,1,1,11).moveTo(dest3.getRange(2,1,1,11)); 
   src.deleteRow(row);
}
}
```